# How to filter uniq sets from two columns of data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL to find possible team combinations.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM members;
+----------+-------+
| IDmember | Name  |
+----------+-------+
|        1 | John  |
|        2 | Harry |
|        3 | Kolb  |
+----------+-------+
```

Then applied this:

```
SELECT t1.IDmember AS ID1
     , t2.IDmember AS ID2
     , t1.Name
     , t2.Name 
  FROM members t1 
  JOIN members t2 
 WHERE t1.IDmember != t2.IDmember;
```

but a WHERE condition is still missing to avoid duplicate teams, like (2,1) and (1,2); (3,2) and (2,3); (1,3) and (3,1):

```
+-----+-----+-------+-------+
| ID1 | ID2 | Name  | Name  |
+-----+-----+-------+-------+
|   2 |   1 | Harry | John  |
|   3 |   1 | Kolb  | John  |
|   1 |   2 | John  | Harry |
|   3 |   2 | Kolb  | Harry |
|   1 |   3 | John  | Kolb  |
|   2 |   3 | Harry | Kolb  |
+-----+-----+-------+-------+
```

How can i improve this query?

Comment: use `t1.IDmember < t2.IDmember` or `t1.IDmember > t2.IDmember` to get one combination only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close:

```
SELECT t1.IDmember AS ID1, t2.IDmember AS ID2, t1.Name, t2.Name
FROM members t1 INNER JOIN
     members t2 
     ON t1.IDmember < t2.IDmember;
```

That is, replace `!=` with `<`.

Editorial note:  If you use `INNER JOIN`, then include an `ON` clause.  If you put the condition in the `WHERE`, then use `CROSS JOIN`.  I think MySQL is the only database that allows `INNER JOIN` with no `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd do:

```
SELECT
    t1.IDmember AS ID1,
    t2.IDmember AS ID2,
    t1.Name,
    t2.Name
FROM
    members t1
    CROSS JOIN members t2
WHERE
    t1.IDmember < t2.IDmember;
```

The member with the lower ID will be "player 1"